# How to display chinese characters in a editbox in visual studio 6

Tags: visual-c++

I am developing an application which has to parse a xml file and display the content in an edit box control.But my xml file may have Chinese,Japanese or Hindi in some cases .When I am reading a xml file,I am getting the content like "?????". Because of which I am getting the same in the edit box also.

How to display Chinese characters without changing the character set to UNICODE?Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried with UTF-8?

Comment: I have tried some conversion which ends up in failure.I am getting getting some different characters which is not matching with the one present in the XML file.

Comment: Is it possible to get some sample code to achieve this?

Comment: @Arjit Thanks bro, solved my issue.